# How to automatically run a command after exiting ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

How can I automatically run a command on the local terminal after exiting a `ssh` connection? Is there any hook or event that could be handled for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Leverage an `alias` or better a function.

For example:

```
ssh () { command ssh "$@"; echo foobar; }
```

Now, you can run:

```
ssh mysite
```

after you exit from the `ssh` session, `echo foobar` will be run.

Change `echo foobar` with the actual command you need to run, and of course you can tack multiple commands if you want.

To make the function definition permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc`.

---

Also note that, it might not always be desired to have the function named as `ssh` when you want to explicitly use the external `ssh`. In that case, you can use any one of the following to skip the `ssh` function to get external `ssh` binary:

```
command ssh mysite
```

or rename the function to something else e.g. `sshfunc`:

```
sshfunc () { ssh "$@"; echo foobar; }
```

Comment: note: I recommend renaming the function to something else than "ssh", so you keep ssh it's original meaning...  maybe:  ssh2 ? or  sshcmd ? (otherwise you could forget its side effects when doing things like: `ssh user@host 'cd /somewhere/ && tar cf - | gzip -c -' > local_backup_of_somewhere.tgz` :  this will be wrong as it will contain "foobar" at the end...)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Good point, edited.

Comment: \ssh 'ssh' and "ssh" only escapes an alias, command ssh will run the command (escaping both alias and function).

Comment: @OlivierDulac Didn't know that, fixed.

Comment: It is like that in bash, can maybe vary with other shells... but now, I like your answer with those additions, you get my +1 ^^