# how to close/reuse ssh LocalForward ports

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, autossh

I need to ssh to multiple hosts having this configuration:

```
Protocol 2
ExitOnForwardFailure yes
ServerAliveCountMax 1
ServerAliveInterval 3
TCPKeepAlive no
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%C
ControlPersist 10m

Host targetA
  HostName      <server-ip>
  User          user-name
  LocalForward  8888 localhost:8888
  LocalForward  3306 localhost:3306

Host targetB
  HostName      <server-ip>
  User          user-name
  LocalForward  8888 localhost:8888
  LocalForward  3306 localhost:3306
```

After connecting to host `targetA` and then trying to connect to `targetB` I get this error:

```
bind [127.0.0.1]:8888: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
```

Therefore I need to kill existing connections to be available to connect to `targetB` and use the same ports `8888` & `3306`, something like this:

```
lsof -ti:8888,3306 | xargs -L1 kill -9
```

or

```
ssh -O exit targetA
```

This works but would like to know if there is a way to simplify this process, probably with something in `~.ssh/config`, and continue to have the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options besides still using same ports.

Tried already something like `ProxyCommand sh -c "script.sh; ssh %h %p"` without success.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400438/315749